# Route53 and ElasticBeanstalk, How to make DNS records durable to app updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've got an ElasticBeanstalk app that's setup to appear when you visit a domain I own. Specifically, I've got my domain registrars name servers pointing to AWS, and an A record in Route53 that points my custom domain to the IP addresses of the ElasticBeanstalk app. I got these IP addresses using `host` and the app's URL.

Everything worked fine for awhile, but then it appears the IP addresses of the app changed somehow (I didn't push any updates), and it stopped working (with a 504 bad gateway – no surprise considering the addresses changed).

How can you configure Route53 records to remain durable to these types of changes to the ElasticBeanstalk app? Is it possible to not have to update Route53 when you update the app?

Comment: Are you sure you used Elastic IP of your EB instance?

Comment: Not 100% sure. Don't think that I am using Elastic IP. My EC2 dashboard says that I have 0 elastic IPs. Perhaps I need to set one up?

Comment: If its not EIP, then are you using load-balanced EB environment? Then you should use its url for your R53, not any IP address.